# Regarding function pointer in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers, void-pointers

I am beginner in C language and was learning about function pointer in C language. There I encountered a problem?

**Write a compare function to sort by first character of name?**

**int (*firstnamecharcompar)(const void * a, const void * b))**

Here is my code solution for this.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int compare1(const void *a,const void *b)
{
    char *c = *(char**)a;
    char *d = *(char**)b;
    return c[0] - d[0];
    //return ( *(char*)a[0] == *(char*)b[0] );
}

int main()
{
    char str[3][10];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter %d string => " , i+1 );
        scanf("%s", str[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("%s ",str[i]);
    }
    
    qsort(str,3,10,compare1);
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("%s ",str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But my code is getting terminated without giving any output?
What is problem with my code?

Comment: Start by using a *debugger* to catch any possible crash, and locate when and where it happens in your code. Then examine the values of all involved variables to make sure they all look valid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thinks it's all fine..

Comment: @folibis `3` is correct yes, but since each element in the `str` array is `10` bytes the second "size" is correct in the code.

Comment: @folibis sizeof(char) would be 1 Bytes but here each str is of 10 bytes

Comment: If all was fine, then it wouldn't crash, right? So there must be *something* wrong.... ;) Using a debugger is the correct way to start solving such problems.

Comment: Your compare function assumes you are sorting an array of pointers but your main function has an array of arrays. Pointers and arrays are not the same thing.

Comment: @JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer I don't think so it should be char *c = (char*)a; char *d = (char*)b. Because it will types case it to character but we need array of character

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Okay but how to fix this issue?

Comment: You need to decide what you want first, an array of pointers to char or an array of char arrays. Both approaches are valid.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I have solved this by first making array of character pointers and then dynamically allocating it memory to hold string. But again not giving any output.

Comment: You may want to ask a different question with relevant code. (Incidentally, "solved" doesn't look like a correct word in this case).

Answer (score 5):

```
char *c = *(char**)a;
char *d = *(char**)b;
```

These lines would be valid if you were sorting an array of pointers to `char`. You are in fact sorting an array of 10-element `char` arrays. Adjust the casts accordingly:

```
char *c = *(char(*)[10])a;
char *d = *(char(*)[10])b;
```

Comment: Thanks solved the issue. So if we are using string as 2d array so we need to type cast accrodingly.

Comment: But what if we have used char* str[3];   for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
  str[i] = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
 }

Comment: @Hashinclude Then you have a different question.

Comment: Okay, then how we need to type-cast void pointer in compare1 function?

Comment: @Hashinclude Not sure what you mean. The answer shows exactly what needs to be done with `compare1` without touching the rest of the program. If you have a problem with a different program, please ask a separate question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69008950/function-pointer-in-c Here is my question?